# Автотесты после перехода на TFS 2017 не проходят

Tags: автоматизация, tfs

После перехода на TFS 2017 Перестали проходить выпуски автотестов, до этого всё работало нормально. Может кто-то сталкивался? 
На шаге Deploy TestAgent падает. Лог прикрепил.
Побывал новый/старый/по умолчанию из интернета TestAgent, ничего не помогает.

```
2017-01-16T16:01:54.5637950Z ##[warning]DistributedTests: Произошла ошибка задачи "ConfigureTestAgent" для компьютера wlab-34.zav.mir:5985: System.Exception: TestAgent Configuration failed with exit code . Error code : -1.
```

[Ссылка на отчет](http://lab-27.ru/tasklog_3.log)

[image: Скриншот шагов выпуска и отчета]

Comment: откуда куда. что, когда. какие шаги. прикрепите  к вопросу

Comment: кажись отсутствуют права `zav\autorazv needs to be given permission on Tfs`

Comment: что за функция в DeployTestAgent.ps1 на 5985 строке? приложите к вопросу, если можете

Comment: Не смог найти этот файл на реальной машине, но думаю, что это [оно](https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/blob/master/Tasks/DeployVisualStudioTestAgent/DeployTestAgent.ps1)

Comment: локально без ошибок работает на тестовом стенде?

Comment: На самой машине, где пишу тесты и запускаю через VS2015? Да

Comment: там подключаются скрипты. в каких скриптах пишет `Сбой задачи развертывания агента тестирования на всех компьютерах. ` ?

Comment: В этом релизе была ошибка, кириллица в названии проектов не поддерживалась, отправили отчет в майкрософт, они исправили в следующем upd.

Answer (score 0):

Проблема была в том, что присутствует кириллица в названиях проектов.